# Подсчитать сопротивление параллельного включения

Tags: java

Написал код который должен по идее решить эту задачу "Три сопротивления R1, R2, R3 соединены параллельно. Найти сопротивление соединения." в коде вылазеет 5 ошибок и все они показывают что то вроде "error: class, interface, or enum expected" подскажите что в коде можно исправить или дополнить?
Cам код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getRezultRezey(200, 300, 200));
    }

    private static double getRezultRezey(double... rezist){
        double provod = 0;
        for (double aR : rezist)
            provod += Math.pow(aR, -1);
        return Math.pow(provod, -1);
    }
```

p.s. код пишу на Netbeans на JAVA GRADLE

Comment: А метод main у вас в каком то классе находится?

Comment: Вы программу в ручную компилируете? Если да то покажите команду которую вы пишите и класс в ктором у вас находится метод main

Comment: Скорее всего вы или не указали класс и просто написали метод main, или у вас в одном файле два открытых класса. а так нельзя

Comment: @DevJ извиняюсь я совсем про класс забыл, java я занимаюсь очень немного дня 2, я ввел класс public class Resistance но вышла другая ошибка "error: class Resistance is public, should be declared in a file named Resistance.java
public class Resistance {"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для правильной компиляции и последующей сборки вашей программы, сначало необходимо указать класс, далее в нем метод main, после чего сохранить файл с ЕДИНСТВЕННЫМ открытым классом. Файл должен обезательно иметь расширение .java и его имя должно быть точно такое-же как и ваш открытый класс.

```
public class Resistance {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

           getRezultRezey(300,200,100);
    }

    private static double getRezultRezey(double... rezist) {
         //реализация вашего метода
    }

}
```

И сохраните все это с расширением .java и назовите ваш файл точно так-же как и ваш класс, тоесть Resistance. После чего напишите в командной строке javac Resistance.java и соответственно запустите программу java Resistance